# How are memory_order_seq_cst fences useful anymore in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, memory-barriers, memory-model

Consider this code:

```cpp
std::atomic<int> x{ 0 };
std::atomic<int> y{ 0 };
int a;
int b;

void thread1()
{
    //atomic op A
    x.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    //fence X
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    //sequenced-before P, thus in SC order X=>P

    //atomic op P
    a = y.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);//0
    //reads-before(from-read) Q, thus in SC order P=>Q
}

void thread2()
{
    //atomic op Q
    y.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    //sequenced-before B, thus in SC order Q=>B

    //atomic op B
    b = x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t2(thread2);
    std::thread t1(thread1);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    assert(a == 1 || b == 1);//true?
    return 0;
}
```

The question is: is the assertion `a == 1 || b == 1` always true in C++20?

I think it's true in C++17. The idea is this: first assume a get 0, then prove b must get 1. Let's split it into two parts:

##### 1. Fence X precedes atomic op B in the SC total order

- X is sequenced-before P, thus X=>P
- P reads 0 and Q writes 1, thus P reads-before(from-read) Q, thus P=>Q

  - I don't find the clause in the standard that guarantees this, but [this paper](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/scfix/paper.pdf) said so. Please point out if I get it wrong. **Edit**: Now I know. It's the same rule about *coherence-ordered before*, as in Nate's answer.
- Q is sequenced-before B, thus Q=>B

##### 2. Atomic op B reads the value(1) written by atomic op A

C++17 has this in the standard:

> For atomic operations A and B on an atomic object M, where A modifies M and B takes its value, if there is a memory_order::seq_cst fence X such that A is sequenced before X and B follows X in S, then B observes either the effects of A or a later modification of M in its modification order.

It's exactly the case here. Op A and B are on atomic object x, where A stores 1 in x and B reads x's value; and there is the seq_cst fence X; A is sequenced before X and B follows X in S(the above); and there's no modification of M later than A. So B observes the value written by A. So b gets 1.

Is the above reasoning correct?

But in C++20, the above sited text about fences is removed (by [P0668](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html)), and upgraded to "strengthened" seq_cst fences, which reads:

> An atomic operation A on some atomic object M is coherence-ordered before another atomic operation B on
> M if
>
> - A is a modification, and B reads the value stored by A, or
> - A precedes B in the modification order of M, or
> - A and B are not the same atomic read-modify-write operation, and there exists an atomic modification
>   X of M such that A reads the value stored by X and X precedes B in the modification order of M, or
> - there exists an atomic modification X of M such that A is coherence-ordered before X and X is
>   coherence-ordered before B.
>
> There is a single total order S on all memory_order::seq_cst operations, including fences, that satisfies the following constraints. First, if A and B are memory_order::seq_cst operations and A strongly happens before B, then A precedes B in S. Second, for every pair of atomic operations A and B on an object M, where A is coherence-ordered before B, the following four conditions are required to be satisfied by S:
>
> - if A and B are both memory_order::seq_cst operations, then A precedes B in S; and
> - if A is a memory_order::seq_cst operation and B happens before a memory_order::seq_cst fence
>   Y , then A precedes Y in S; and
> - if a memory_order::seq_cst fence X happens before A and B is a memory_order::seq_cst operation,
>   then X precedes B in S; and
> - if a memory_order::seq_cst fence X happens before A and B happens before a memory_order::seq_-
>   cst fence Y , then X precedes Y in S.

I don't see how `a==1 || b==1` is guaranteed any more. It's only about how SC fences are ordered with regard to other SC operations, or operations that are coherence-ordered with each other.

I can't find anything else about how SC fences interact with non-SC atomic operations in the C++20 standard, and a load that does *not* see a value from a store doesn't mean it's coherence-ordered before the store. (Or does it?  If so that would fix the problem; see comments) [31.4 : 3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics#order-3.2) applies when *A precedes B in the modification order of M*, but reads aren't part of the modification order of an object, are they?

Is it I didn't look into the standard hard enough, or the code simply doesn't work any more in C++20? If it's the later, is the regression
intended? (In P0668, they claim to "strengthen" fences).

Comment: Yes, in C++17 `a == 1 || b == 1` is guaranteed. Relaxed store + seq_cst barrier is at least as strong as a seq_cst store, and any interleaving of source order has at least one load after the store in the other thread.  I don't know about C++20 yet, haven't read the details.  I expect it's still something the committee wants to be true, so if there is a change that might be a defect.  (But I don't expect real-world implementations would change how they compile it, so in practice everything's fine on normal CPUs, of course.)

Comment: *It's only about how SC fences are ordered with regard to other SC operations.* - not exactly.  The "*Second,*" clause is about any pair of operations on the same object M that are coherence-ordered, e.g. including an mo_relaxed load that happens to see a value from an mo_relaxed store. (https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics#order-3.1).  But I'm not sure it applies for a load that *doesn't* see a stored value.  3.2 "A precedes B in the modification order of M" wouldn't apply if A is a read, not a modification, I think?  If it does apply, then so would the SC fence bullet list.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! I see your point. If you count *reads the value of M before a write to M* (aka "reads-before") as *coherence-ordered before*, you can assume `a==0 && b==0` then say B(the load of x) is coherence-ordered before A(the store of x). Then applying the second bullet list : "*- if A is a memory_order::seq_cst operation and B happens before a memory_order::seq_cst fence Y , then A precedes Y in S;*", you get B=>X in S. That's a circle in S (X=>P=>Q=>B=>X), which is prohibited. So `a==0 && b==0` cannot be true.

Comment: The standard text does not seem to say that "reads-before" is "coherence-ordered before". Since the word "coherence" in the name, maybe it should be?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as-written, reading the old value does not make a load coherence-ordered before a store.  (But yes, if it did, that would engage the SC fence rules to do what they should).  It's possible for one thread to see a store to object M while another thread still sees the old value (e.g. [on real HW via store-forwarding between SMT threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50679223/224132)), and IDK what other parts of the standard depend on coherence-ordered ops, so IDK if this could repair the standard without breaking anything else.

Comment: If a read happens-before a write, it's guaranteed not to see the value (by [the read-write coherence rule, 6.9.2.1 :: 17](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-17)).  But again, I don't think not seeing the value implies anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think we can prove that `a == 1 || b == 1` is always true.  Most of the ideas here were worked out in comments by zwhconst and Peter Cordes, so I just thought I would write it up as an exercise.

(Note that X, Y, A, B below are used as the dummy variables in the standard's axioms, and may change from line to line.  They do not coincide with the labels in your code.)

**Suppose `b = x.load()` in thread2 yields 0.**

We do have the coherence ordering that you asked about.  Specifically, if `b = x.load` yields 0, then I claim that `x.load()` in thread2 is coherence ordered before `x.store(1)` in thread1, thanks to the third bullet in the definition of coherence ordering.  For let A be `x.load()`, B be `x.store(1)`, and X be the initialization `x{0}` (see below for quibble).  Clearly X precedes B in the modification order of `x`, since X happens-before B (synchronization occurs when the thread is started), and if `b == 0` then A has read the value stored by X.

(There is possibly a gap here: initialization of an atomic object is not an atomic operation (3.18.1p3), so as worded, the coherence ordering does not apply to it.   I have to believe it was intended to apply here, though.  Anyway, we could dodge the issue by putting `x.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed);` in `main` before starting the threads, which would still address the spirit of your question.)

Now in the definition of the ordering S, apply the second bullet with A = `x.load()` and B = `x.store(1)` as before, and Y being the `atomic_thread_fence` in thread1.  Then A is coherence-ordered before B, as we just showed; A is `seq_cst`; and B happens-before Y  by sequencing.  So therefore A = `x.load()` precedes Y = `fence` in the order S.

**Now suppose `a = y.load()` in thread1 also yields 0.**

By a similar argument to before, `y.load()` is coherence ordered before `y.store(1)`, and they are both `seq_cst`, so `y.load()` precedes `y.store(1)` in S.  Also, `y.store(1)` precedes `x.load()` in S by sequencing, and likewise  `atomic_thread_fence` precedes `y.load()` in S.  We therefore have in S:

- `x.load` precedes `fence` precedes `y.load` precedes `y.store` precedes `x.load`

which is a cycle, contradicting the strict ordering of S.

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't grokked that 3rd bullet point before.  I think I saw RMW and stopped looking, wrongly assuming what it was going to be about.  So the load *is* coherence-ordered before the store if it doesn't see the value.  (Agreed about static initialization counting as the X operation to match the intent of that wording).  And yes, then all the other pieces fall into place once we can justify calling that coherence ordering.

Comment: Nice! Now I know what "*not the same*" means in English :P