# Demonstrate LoadStore reordering with a load getting a value round-tripped to another thread, in practice with relaxed load/store?

Tags: c++, x86, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers, memory-model

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

void test_relaxed()
{
    using namespace std;
    atomic<int> x{0};
    atomic<int> y{0};

    std::thread t1([&] {
        auto r1 = y.load(memory_order_relaxed); //a
        x.store(r1, memory_order_relaxed); //b
        });

    std::thread t2([&] {
        auto r2 = x.load(memory_order_relaxed); //c
        y.store(42, memory_order_relaxed); //d
    });
    
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

According to cppreference ([in a relaxed ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) example), the above code is allowed to produce `r1 == r2 == 42`.

But I have tested it on x86-64 and arm64 platforms and I cannot get this result. Is there any way to get it in practice with real compilers and CPUs?

([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gEADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/qRJKY4CIWGRLDFxZgF2mA5pQgRMxAQZPn4VmPb5DLX1BIUR0bHxtnUNTVkVwz2hfSUD5QCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbkxELHimG9gmGgCCm9u7mAdHBAjEmEzoh1e31zcAbqg8Og9gRMAoCAB9d4GVSYdAQOZ/EwAdistz2mL2XhSRj2zDYCgSTFWewhXw26JuWL2J1QZwublCBG%2Be1UqIsGlRABFDlSaXSGYcmYJWQBPDlclG8ynIjFY8kgECvd6fUFcCAmACsVjMADZtdyDmi/jSBV4iHtiFxnkaxQA6WioT4QNgsEhiyEkLDEaFtJhw9BIyl7AD0oaYprNmNU9ohJEwEGtpD2bo9XuIPr9sPhwYsYdDUSj0Z5ebl1IVBHQSpVHxBBDMmp15gNWqNHOLZqYFtQVrMtrZjudCLTxE93ti2YDub5BdM8ujDvj7wgkgCqcw7rHGazMOnQdn4a%2BC%2BN3LLJ87BC49u0QIYiL5l7MN7vD9lv2lHAWtE4Wt4fg4LRSFQTg3GsawySWFYnk2HhSAITQvwWBA6wGRFSAAaxADYNntHD8IIwi9X0ThJH/RDgM4XgFBADR4MQhY4FgJA0BYBI6FichKFY9j6DieoWD1SRgC4co6Kwf5zkwAA1PBMAAdwAeQSRhODgmhaDBYgaIgKIKKiUJ6jFNTeAM5gx0UqJtCqBDuF4Vi2EERSGFoYzAN4LAWEMYBxHc0h8Heap/nBCjMDhZALTWODmTaCjaDwKJiCMjwsAoghiDwFgTIWKgDGABRZIU5TVLsmRBBEMR2CkMr5CUNQKN0Lh9G8lBwMsfQEpoyAFlQBIOhojgAFpFLMai2hstIXAYdxPGaPRgimYpSj0XJUgEUY/Ca1aOl6JaBiaypqgELoRlmrIDvGo7OgmXb%2BjiA6Jg2vQIW6W6ZnuhYFCg1YJG/X9yL8kCOD2G4ACUAFkhL2YBkGQPZRPtZ8ND2CBcEIEgDjMDYuDmXhbK0OYFiwnC8MIsmcOIn8ODI0gsq4DQ6IAoCgeo2j6PcxiYEQFB6V4ziKAgHiOLiETyn8zBJNWQqlJUgD1LoLSdL0vyzKMkzSFViyrJs9WHMYAhnNcijPO83ygICibgoGoCwqqSL1ZiqmgPixLkowNYgPSzLsr4PKCrkmWSvU2QKvEar%2BEERQVHUPzdACAwjFayxrA6qIuvQ3r%2Bs4YagMOjoppmzJNsCaa3uWrbkjW9IzuL7a0jL/bbEujoTsaGvnubmobsWu7nse9uHtenv3t%2BxZlh%2BnGSI4P9SCZ3ggbZAAOPVBqhmG4YR/tUfwIhiEx7HcfZgmiew3DyfJqeabnyiOFZuj8aQqfRtniiWaPx/gu0ybJCAA))

Comment: I think you are unlikely to see it in practice, because compilers are currently very conservative with atomics and don't do transformations like reordering `//c` and `//d` which they are technically allowed to. And on the CPU level for x86 the strong memory model also assures this won't happen. On ARM with weaker memory model I think you should be able to observe it, but I don't know what exact conditions are required.

Comment: But in the end it doesn't really matter, since we don't know whether compilers will do such transformations in the future. I would simply write against the spec.

Comment: I looped it for 1000000 times, but failed get it on my iphone

Comment: Suppose someone can argue that with current compilers and x86/ARM CPUs this can never happen. What would we have gained from that insight? It wouldn't change that the outcome is _allowed_.

Comment: just curious...I found its much easier for learning such sophiscated topic if we had some real-world example.

Comment: I do think it's an interesting question: not as a question about C++ (for which the theoretical memory model's answer is clear), but as a question about how a microarchitecture could allow this to happen.  You may want to change the tags.

Comment: I played with this a bit on ARM64, but couldn't get it to happen.  I have it in a loop where t2 stores an incrementing counter, alternating with the load.  Thread t1 is likewise in an infinite loop.  I aligned x and y so they are in different cache lines.  I also tried various things to delay load c, like making the machine fetch the address of `x` from a page that has just been evicted from cache, or making it "compute" the address of x via a long series of udiv or fsqrt.  But still can't observe it, on Cortex A-72 or Apple M1.

Comment: @NateEldredge added the tag.

Comment: On x86-64, this could only happen if the compiler chose to reorder at compile-time.  The x86 memory model is program order plus a store-buffer with store forwarding, which only allows StoreLoad plus the quirks of threads seeing their own stores before they're globally visible.  https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/.  https://preshing.com/20121019/this-is-why-they-call-it-a-weakly-ordered-cpu/ has some practical reordering tests on ARM

Comment: @NateEldredge: If you forget to compile with optimization, GCC won't inline `x.store` and so on, and run-time variable `memory_order` gets treated as `seq_cst` instead of branching. https://godbolt.org/z/6rz43a716  The other possible problem is thread startup taking much longer than the reordering window created by store-buffer latency, but you're already working around that by retrying with already-started threads; Preshing's https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ x86 StoreLoad test has a sync and random delay before doing one test.

Comment: Separate cache lines for the variables is necessary; we need the `x.load` to miss in cache so badly that it doesn't take a value until after a round trip to the other thread.  And probably that it doesn't even *start* a load with a known address until then, e.g. if many other cache misses are outstanding?  A dep chain for the load address won't let the later store retire until it's completed, because all of that is before the store, unless we statically (compile-time) reorder the store.

Comment: @NateEldredge - The load itself can't retire until its address is non-speculative; else the CPU must assume it could fault.  With the store later, it can't retire and commit from the store buffer until after that.  So we can't just delay the address.  Perhaps generate may outstanding cache misses to other lines.  (And have the other reader thread spin-wait for a non-zero value and then store that, so you don't need its one load to be perfectly timed to minimize latency.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Oh, good point about the possibility of faulting.  I'm trying the cache miss approach now but no luck so far.  (And yes, I did make sure to enable optimization, and double checked the generated assembly too - but it's always worth asking!)

Comment: @NateEldredge: Have a look at my answer; another idea was to have other threads contend for access to the cache line holding `x`, as well as or instead of having thread 2 have a bunch of in-flight cache miss loads before reaching this code.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'll give it a try, thanks.  I also thought of replacing the load with a `ldadd` using a delayed value of zero, in hopes that it might delay the load as well as the store, but no joy there either.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Delaying any input to the load (address or RMW data) means it can't retire as soon.  Since retirement is in-order (to maintain precise exceptions), that means the store can't retire as soon either, so you're no farther ahead on getting the store ahead of the load. (I intended my answer to make that point, but maybe it's a bit buried and you just skimmed.) Definitely for an ALU delay chain since at least the last insn in the chain would have to retire, but probably even if the `0` came from one cache-miss load. I don't think the `ldadd` could retire while still waiting for input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the ARM Memory Tool ([the article](https://developer.arm.com/Architectures/Memory%20Model%20Tool), [the online tool](http://diy.inria.fr/www/?record=aarch64)) `arm64` allows this behavior (which means it might occur on some `arm64` cpus).

The following is a litmus test for your example:

```
AArch64 SO-q-2023-03-06
{
0:X1=x; 0:X3=y;
1:X1=y; 1:X3=x;
}
 P0          | P1          ;
 LDR W0,[X1] | LDR W0,[X1] ;
 STR W0,[X3] | MOV W2,#42  ;
             | STR W2,[X3] ;
exists
(0:X0=42 /\ 1:X0=42)
```

You can try it yourself in [the online tool](http://diy.inria.fr/www/?record=aarch64).

But there could be problems with finding the `arm64` hardware that displays such behavior.

I have no data for `arm64`, but there is such data for ARMv7 (it might give you insight, or you might want to try to reproduce you example on ARMv7).
You test case is very similar to [`LB+data+po`](https://diy.inria.fr/cats/model-newgeneration/unseen-LB+data+po.html) litmus test.
The results for the litmus test on different hardware is [here](https://diy.inria.fr/cats/model-newgeneration/compare.html#top@unseen-LB+data+po): as you can see, it reproduces only on some hardware.
Meaning of the hardware abbreviations used in the table is given [here](https://diy.inria.fr/cats/simulator.html).

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks.  Though LB+data+po is also explainable if the machine can break the false input dependency in `EOR R1, R0, R0`.  The ARMv8 memory model is pretty explicit that it must not do so, but ARMv7 is a little more vague on the point.

Comment: Testd on M1 pro, never manage to get it happen. https://tinypic.host/i/qi-ye-wei-xin-jie-tu-7fb1cef1-c874-4f78-b4ad-d10e8bab3068.JZja5

Comment: Tested on Allwinner_H6(which is armv8-A arch), Negative.

Comment: Tested on RK3588s(a76+a75), negative.

Comment: Tested on JH.7110(risc-v), negative.

Answer (score 2):

On x86-64, this could only happen if the compiler chose to reorder at compile-time. The x86 memory model is program order plus a store-buffer with store forwarding, which only allows [StoreLoad](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) plus the quirks of threads seeing their own stores before they're globally visible.  (Neither thread is doing that here.)  https://preshing.com/20121019/this-is-why-they-call-it-a-weakly-ordered-cpu/ has some practical reordering tests on ARM, but not this one.

I think it's theoretically possible on ARM / AArch64, but only with an extremely slow response to a MESI share request for `x`.  Perhaps multiple other cores spamming atomic RMWs on it, like `x.fetch_add(0)` in other threads?  (Beware of clang optimizing no-op RMWs to just memory barriers without touching the cache line).  Or incomplete LDXR / STXR transactions that don't actually modify it?  Maybe with hand-written asm with `ldxr` / `clrex` if that's a thing in 64-bit mode.

Or more simply, a 3rd and 4th thread spamming stores (and maybe loads) on a different part of the same cache line holding `x`.

---

Separate cache lines for the variables is necessary (so use `alignas(64) std::atomic<int> x {0};` etc.) We need thread 2's `x.load` (C) to miss in cache so badly that it doesn't take a value until after a round trip to the other thread.  And probably that thread 2 doesn't even send out (to other cores) a request to read the cache line until long after its store has retired and committed to L1d cache.  Otherwise the request will go out to other cores before thread 1 has even dirtied that cache line, so data will just come in from DRAM, or from the main thread's store since it's a local on the stack.

A long dependency chain for the load address like Nate tried won't help, unfortunately.  That would work if you could delay the load that way without delaying visibility of the store that follows it, but that's not the case due to the way out-of-order exec works.  (In-order exec of course automatically delays all later instructions when earlier instructions are slow.)

Stores can't become visible to other cores (commit from the store buffer to L1d cache<sup>1</sup>) until after they retire from out-of-order exec, because they're still speculative until then.  And speculation needs to be kept private within one core so only it has to roll back on detection of mis-speculation.  See *[Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram)*  (All instructions that could potentially fault are speculated, not just branches.)

So the store `D` can't retire until after the load address for `C` is ready and the load itself sent to an execution unit, unless the compiler statically (in the asm) reorders the store before the load.  It's allowed to do that, but it won't do so for no reason.  And compilers don't (currently) optimize atomics, so an earlier store of `y` to get the compiler to do dead-store elimination won't work, nor will other operations on `x`.

---

**If the core running thread 2 sends out a MESI share request due to `x.load()` at about the same time it sends out a RFO (Read For Ownership) due to `y.store()`, it's going to get replies to both within a pretty narrow window.**  Far too little time for another core to read the store value and and have modified the cache line holding `x` before receiving and responding to the share request.

At least under normal conditions; with heavy contention for the cache line holding `x`, the reply could be delayed a lot, with some other threads getting a turn (giving time for `y.store` to be seen by `y.load` in thread 1).

But the `x.store` in thread 1 (B) won't happen until one hop of inter-thread-latency after `y.store` in thread 2 (D). And the `x.load` in thread 1 (C) will have had all that time to get its turn to read that cache line.

Perhaps it could help to have a lot of previous cache misses (to scattered addresses) in thread 2 oustanding, in hopes that the load could still be sent to an execution unit and retire before there was a free buffer to track an off-core MESI request for it.  If those loads were all `ldapr` acquire loads, it would make sure they had to finish before the relaxed `ldr`.

A non-x86 ISA can retire a load from the out-of-order back-end before the data arrives, as long as the address is known and it's verified that it's non-faulting.  (i.e. TLB hit and valid translation.)  This is how LoadStore reordering is possible at all.

---

#### Other notes on testing methodology:

You need to compile with optimization enabled, otherwise GCC won't inline `x.store` and so on.   Run-time variable `memory_order` gets treated as `seq_cst` instead of branching to maybe skip a fence. https://godbolt.org/z/6rz43a716

Thread startup may take longer than the reordering window; as Nate described in comments, you want to run multiple test after starting a thread.

Perhaps have thread 1 spin until it sees a non-`0` value, then store that.  That removes the need for a timing coincidence there of happening to run at just the right time.   Preshing's https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act x86 StoreLoad test has a sync and random delay before doing one test, to maximize the chance both threads are really running at the same time, not having one finish before the OS can get to starting the 2nd one on a different core.

---

**Footnote 1**: it's also possible for a core to make retired ("graduated") stores visible to some other cores before retirement: some POWER CPUs have store-forwarding between local cores of the same physical core.  See *[Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see)*.  ARMv8 doesn't allow that, and no earlier ARM CPUs ever did it.  x86 also requires that all thread can agree on a total order for all stores (not loads).