# x86 sequential consistency with a mfence

Tags: memory, concurrency, x86

I'm trying to understand how a mfence guarantees sequential consistency on x86.

Take this code for example

```cpp
std::atomic<int> a,b,r;

void write_a()
{
    a.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);    
}

void write_b()
{
    b.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);    
}

void read_a_b()
{
    while(!a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));
    if(b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        r++;
    }
}

void read_b_a()
{
    while(!b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));
    if(a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        r++;
    }
}
```

gcc 9.5 with -O3 generates following assembly for the `write_a` and `write_b` functions

```
write_a():
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 1
        mfence
        ret
write_b():
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 1
        mfence
        ret
```

When a `std::memory_order_release` stores are used, then the code becomes

```
write_a():
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 1
        ret
write_b():
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 1
        ret
```

so essentially the mfence is just dropped.

Now to my understanding with sequential-consistency a result `r==0` is impossible. Whereas with acquire-release ordering it is theoretically possible.

As far as I know, mfence makes sure that the store buffer gets "flushed" and every store and load that follows it is stalled until the memory operations before the mfence have completed globally.
However in my example, after the mfence no other memory operation follow, so I don't understand how it makes any difference in regards to the sequential consistent visibility of the changes to a and b.

In particular what happens if thread1 executed `mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 1` but has not yet started executing `mfence` and thread2 analogously executed `mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 1` but not yet started executing `mfence`.

```
write_a():
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 1 <- thread1 finished this operation
        mfence                      <- thread1 has not yet executed this operation
        ret
write_b():
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 1 <- thread2 finished this operation
        mfence                      <- thread2 has not yet executed this operation
        ret
```

At this time point, the code executed so far is the same as the code generated for the `std::memory_order_release` stores. So up to this point only a "release" stores took place.

Now if we have thread3 executing read_a_b() and thread4 executing read_b_a()
I believe they could still disagree upon the order of the writes to a and b, so a result of r==0 is still theoretically possible. Only after thread1 and thread2 execute their respective mfences, this would no longer be possible.

What am I getting wrong?

I know that gcc10 uses xchng instead of mov, mfence but my underlying problem remains the same

Comment: That's the IRIW litmus test.  In ISO C++, only `seq_cst` requires all threads to agree on order of stores, but in practice only a few ISAs are that weak in hardware even with relaxed stores and acquire loads, like PowerPC. ([Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27807118).  ARMv7 allowed it on paper but no real ISAs did it.  ARMv8 doesn't allow it, being multi-copy atomic.  x86-TSO is far stronger, with even acq / rel being free.  You're right, `mfence` is 100% irrelevant here.

Comment: Thank you! So as far as I now understand, TSO assures that each processor will see all writes happening in the same order, no matter what processor the writes are originating from (except for  processors seeing their own stores in store buffer first). Making the result `r==0` in my example impossible even without mfence, right?

Comment: Correct, only PowerPC and NVidia GPUs make `r==0` possible.  ARMv7 allowed it on paper but no real hardware was that weak (no mechanism for stores to become visible to some cores before others, only by committing to coherent L1d cache, like on x86.)  Having all cores agree on the order of two independent stores is actually pretty easy / hard to violate; you need some funky stuff like private store-forwarding between SMT threads on the same physical core to make it happen.

Comment: It might be more interesting to look at the the amount of barriers a `seq_cst` load needs on PowerPC, at least one of which is I think only there to prevent IRIW reordering.   https://godbolt.org/z/EKf6E6cGe  - interesting; the only barrier in a seq_cst store is a full `sync` (full barrier) *before* the store (stw = plain store word).  Nothing to drain the store buffer after; I guess that cost must be part of SC loads since they need a `sync` for IRIW reasons?  And an `isync` after for the acquire semantics.  (The asm would be easier to look at private counters for each reader, not an RMW)