# What is the effect of the change to the definition of release sequences in the C++20 memory model?

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++20, atomic, memory-model

Consider this program:

```cpp
-- Initially --
std::atomic<int> x{0};
int y{0};
    
-- Thread 1 --
y = 1;                                      // A
x.store(1, std::memory_order_release);      // B
x.store(3, std::memory_order_relaxed);      // C

-- Thread 2 --
if (x.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 3) // D
    print(y);                               // E
```

Under the C++11 memory model, [if the program prints anything then it prints 1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0982r1.html).

In the C++20 memory model, [release sequences were changed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release_sequence) to exclude writes performed by the same thread. How does that affect this program? Could it now have a data-race and print either `0` or `1`?

### Notes

This code appears in [P0982R1: Weaken Release Sequences](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0982r1.html) which I believe is the paper that resulted in the changes to the definition of release sequences in C++20. In that particular example, there is a third thread making a store to `x` which disrupts the release sequence in a way that is counter-intuitive. That motivates the need to weaken the release sequence definition.

From reading the paper my understanding is that with the C++20 changes, C will no longer form part of the release sequence headed by B, because C is not a Read-Modify-Write operation. Therefore C does not synchronize with D. Thus there is no *happens-before* relation between A and E.

Since B and C are stores to the same atomic variable and [all threads must agree on the modification order of that variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333661), does the C++20 memory model allow us to infer anything about whether A happens-before E?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; the program has a data race.  The store of 3 does not form part of any release sequence, so D is not synchronized with any release store.  There is thus no way to establish any happens-before relationship between any two operations from the two different threads, and in particular, no happens-before between A and E.

I think the only thing you can infer from the load of 3 is that D definitely does not happen before C; if it did, then D would be obliged to load a value that was strictly earlier in the modification order of `x` [read-write coherence, intro.races p17].  That means in particular that E does not happen before A.

The modification order would come into play if you were to load from `x` again in Thread 2 somewhere after D.  Then you would be guaranteed to load the value 3 again.  That follows from read-read coherence [intro.races p16].  Your second load is not allowed to observe anything that preceded 3 in the modification order, so it cannot load the values 0 or 1.  This would apply even if all the loads and stores in both threads were relaxed.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to understand how you get from "D definitely does not happen before C" to "That means in particular that E does not happen before A". Are you able to give a bit more detail there please?

Comment: @AlastairHarrison: By sequencing, it is clear that D happens before E, and A happens before C.  So if E happens before A, then by transitivity D happens before C, which we just said is not the case.