# Mixing memory orders with/out conditionals

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

Consider the following:

```cpp
std::atomic_bool disabled = true;
int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 1;

[Thread 1]
while (...)
{
    counter2 = ...;
    if (disabled.load(std::memory_order::acquire) && counter2 > counter1) //#1
    {
        disabled.store(false, std::memory_order::relaxed);
        disabled.notify_one();
    }
}

[Thread 2]
while (...)
{
    disabled.wait(true, std::memory_order::relaxed);
    //Do stuff
    counter1 = ...;
    disabled.store(true, std::memory_order::release); //#2
}
```

Is this code guaranteed to behave correctly, i.e. will the load in #1 synchronize with the store in #2 so that the later condition will see the correct value of `counter1`? Can I get away with using relaxed order for the `wait` and `store(false)` or will I have to change them to `acquire/release` as well?

Related scenario:

```cpp
std::atomic_int a = 0;
x = 0;

[Thread 1]
x = 1;
a.store(1, std::memory_order::release);
a.store(2, std::memory_order::relaxed);

[Thread 2]
assert(a.load(std::memory_order::acquire) != 2 || x == 1);
```

In this case, can the assert fail? There are two possibilities I can think of:

1. The 2nd store is able to float above the 1st
2. No reordering but the `store(relaxed)` happening after the 1st breaks the `release/acquire` relationship in the standard. Or in other words: will the last happened-before release synchronize with an acquire (on the same variable of course), given other load/stores with weaker order in between?

For example, for `seq_cst` [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com) says:

> as soon as atomic operations that are not tagged memory_order_seq_cst enter the picture, the sequential consistency guarantee for the program is lost

The context of this question is the standard/memory model and not specific architecture.

Comment: In your second example, without wait/notify, where you modify `x` again *after* a release-store, data-race UB is possible if `a.load(acquire)` sees `2`, since it doesn't synchronize-with anything.  (The value came from a relaxed store, not a release store or an RMW release-sequence).

Comment: In the second example, the 2nd store is not allowed to float above the 1st because of write-write coherence.

Comment: The 2nd assignment is by mistake, and has nothing to do with the focus of this question. Edited.

Comment: Good question. Questions like these are why I prefer to stick with sequentially consistent memory order (and using tools like "address sanitizer", "undefined behaviour sanitizer" and "thread sanitizer" religiously). Writing correct threaded code is *hard enough* as-is ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Thanks. Yeah, I'm replacing my own, perfectly-working, code that uses condition variable + mutex/lock... what can I say, I know I'm looking for trouble but I like that lean, optimized code, binging too much on those C++ memory model/atomics/lock-free talks and articles  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is UB since C++20

> The 2nd store is able to float above the 1st

No, a thread isn't allowed to reorder access to an atomic variable relative to other accesses to the *same* variable. Only (in some cases) relative to other variables.

> No reordering but the store(relaxed) happening after the 1st nullifies the release/acquire relationship in the standard. Or in other words: will the last happened-before release synchronize with an acquire (on the same variable of course), given other load/stores with weaker order in between?

Since C++20 [there's no synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74175556/2752075), so this is a data race. Pre-C++20 this was legal, but apparently didn't actually work on some hardware (in more complex scenarios than this), hence the change.

---

(1) looks fine. But if you put the contents of the second thread in a loop (as implied by otherwise unused `wait()`), then I believe you get UB.

`counter1 = ...;` happens before `counter2 > counter1`, so no race here.

But if the second thread is in a loop, when `counter1 = ...;` happens the second time, that's a data race with preceding `counter2 > counter1`. Replacing `relaxed` with `acquire`/`release` fixes that.

Comment: The `x = 2;` statement is by mistake, and wasn't intended to be the focus of the question. Given your answer and and Peter Cordes comment,  I'll edit the question to remove it.

Comment: Both are in a loop, but I still fail to see the race... as the 2nd thread won't loop until `disabled` is false again and the condition in #1 won't evaluated until `disabled` is true, at that point it's synchronized with the store on #2. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Nieta: `a.load` still doesn't synchronize with thread 1 if loaded a `2` from the relaxed store, as this answer points out.  On paper in the ISO C++ standard, it's *not* guaranteed that you'd see `x == 1`.  (And could still be data-race UB.)  In practice on real hardware, MESI cache coherency means it's definitely fine in this case, a relaxed store by the same thread on the same object will work like a release-sequence.  Even on very weakly-ordered ISAs like PowerPC, things only got weird when there was a 3rd thread involved also accessing `a`.

Comment: @Nieta: If example #1 is in a loop, you have two problems: (a) the load of `counter1` in thread 1 may be reordered after the store of `false` to `disabled`, since the latter store is not release; (b) the store to `counter1` in thread may be reordered before the implicit load in `disabled.wait()`, since the latter is not acquire.  In either case, the accesses to `counter1` will be a data race.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Got it. And just to be clear: if I can guarantee (by some other means) that another, released store, will happen before the acquire load (so the sequence is release->relaxed->release stores, then acquire load) - I would still get synchronization with the last store, right?

Comment: The peculiar thing about the [release sequence issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74175556/2752075) is that if you change `a.store(2, std::memory_order::relaxed)` to `a.exchange(2, std::memory_order_relaxed)` then everything is fine, since a relaxed read-modify write does get to participate in a release sequence.

Comment: @Nieta: If both those code blocks are in a loop, you have bigger problems that I haven't tried to consider.  But yes, for a sequence that runs once, as long as the value you see with an acquire-load came from a release-store that's sequenced after the assignment to `x`, you can read `x` and see the value you assigned.  Because that assignment "happened before" the acquire load.

Comment: HolyBlackCat, Peter Cordes, Nate Eldredge: Excellent. Thanks a lot! The 2nd scenario was purely academic for me but the 1st is very much practical (the usage of the atomic bool replaces a condition variable  + mutex)... I guess my take-aways from all this are: 1. Be very careful when relaxing memory orders 2. Don't mix (load/stores with different order to the same variable) and drive....