# Memory Synchronization with callback called from a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

This is a follow-up question to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77409622/mixing-memory-orders-with-out-conditionals)

I have two threads I wish to synchronize using atomics, and with, say, the most lenient memory order possible...

```cpp
//class members
std::atomic_bool blocked = true;
int counter = 0; //in practice - std::atomic<int>

[Thread 1]
while (...)
{
    counter++; //#4
    if (blocked.load(std::memory_order::acquire))
    {
        // #3
        //Do stuff
        event.set_callback([this]() //#1
        {
            //Executed on another thread
            blocked.store(false, std::memory_order::release); //#2
            blocked.notify_one();
        });
    }
}

[Thread 2]
while (...)
{
    blocked.wait(true, std::memory_order::acquire);
    if (counter > ...) 
    {
    }
    blocked.store(true, std::memory_order::release);
}
```

The callback in #1 will be triggered later by an external event and executed on another thread.

*I'd like to make sure that Thread 2 sees the correct value of `counter` set in Thread 1.*

I've searched for similar questions and in the standard as well, looking to see if there's an implicit `release`-`acquire` synchronization for lambda creation/captures, like `join()` for  threads but couldn't find any.

Questions:

1. Is the code enough to satisfy the requirement above? from the perspective of the C++ memory model it seems the `release` in #2 won't be sufficient since it's performed on a different thread than the one which set `counter`, **but** by common sense I assume that by capturing `this` the lambda will also see the updated state of the object, including the store to `counter` on #4, even if it gets called on a different thread, hence the `release` on Thread 3 *will* make the changes to `counter` visible to Thread 2 by transitivity... (but what if I only capture `blocked`?)
2. If the answer to the above is 'No' - can I make this work using a single atomic variable as above, without resorting to locking that section using a mutex?
   (e.g. I thought about creating a "fake" `acquire`-`release` sequence by placing `blocked.store(true, std::memory_order::release);` on line #3, but this seems... ugly? hacky? an extra store just to prevent reordering)
3. How does the answer change if `counter` is `std::atomic<int>`? e.g. I could `counter.fetch_add(1)` (i.e. `seq_cst`) and this seems enough. In this case will `counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)` also prevent reordering w.r.t to the `load`?

Comment: It depends on how `set_callback` works. If there's `release` inside, and the thread that will call the callback performs `acquire`, then you're fine.

Comment: I don't see how an `acquire` on the callback thread changes anything, as it won't synchronize with any `release` on Thread 1.

Comment: You've got a copy-paste typo: `disabled` seems to mean `blocked`. If there are such typos about `memory_order` in the snippet, you'll get confusing comments. I guess you should carefully read and edit your question.

Comment: @Red.Wave Indeed, thanks. The memory orders are as intended, though...

Comment: @Nieta good. Now at least we can agree on the snippet we are discussing.

Comment: *"as it won't synchronize with any release on Thread 1."* As I said, `set_callback` would have to have a release in it.

Comment: I understand now, the answer is no, it doesn't... (in practice - part of a 3rd party lib)

Comment: (Not only that, it would have to be a `release` on `blocked`, i.e. a *very* specific `set_callback`...)

Comment: Release on any atomic variable would suffice, as long as thread 3 acquires that variable before running the callback.

Comment: In practice, your third-party library likely already provides that guarantee.

Comment: If this is x86, every load in asm is an acquire load (so acq/rel only requires compile-time ordering: acq / rel fences are free other than limiting compile-time reordering.)  So in practice it's probably fine to put `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);` right before `event.set_callback()`, to make any stores it does have release semantics wrt. anything before the fence.  (ping @HolyBlackCat; I'm not sure I fully grokked what this code is doing.  Is `event.set_callback` supposedly an atomic `relaxed` store?  Or in C++ terms it's not `atomic` at all, just de-facto in asm?)

Comment: @PeterCordes Why is it better to use `atomic_thread_fence` (especially considering [this answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61382843/20918996)), than a dummy `blocked.store(true, std::memory_order::release)` in the same place (I'm using MSVC BTW)? And theoretically, do either of these options offer better performance than using a mutex/lock instead, and `relax`ing the loads/stores altogether?

Comment: A release *operation* only has 1-way ordering, unlike a fence. https://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/  And like I said, `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)` compiles to zero asm instructions on x86, only blocking compile-time reordering.  Which in practice already wouldn't happen if the function call doesn't inline.  (Which it can't since you said the library is binary-only so you can't improve it.)

Comment: So a `blocked.store(true, release)` *after* `event.set_callback` could perhaps work if other threads did an acquire load on `blocked` *before* using the callback.  But no, there'd still be a race window where the callback has been set but the release-store hasn't been done.  Unless other threads spin-wait on `blocked` or only run the callback conditionally.  But you talked about this as a dummy store so the reader wouldn't be able to know from the value whether it had happened or not.  I'm still not clear at all on where the callback is used.  Your thread 2 doesn't appear to touch it.

Comment: Of course a `release` would be one way on its own, but combined with the load/acquire of the previous line (the `if`) would practically create a full fence, would it not? However,  if `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)` is a indeed a no-op that's the/an answer I was looking for. I was "concerned" it would emit an `mfence`...

Comment: As for the callback, it is an [openCL event callback](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clSetEventCallback.html), but I don't think it's relevant to the question itself. The specification mentions nothing regarding synchronization, just says that "It is the application's responsibility to ensure that the callback function is thread-safe"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255929/discussion-between-nieta-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: Only `seq_cst` needs to block StoreLoad reordering with `mfence` or a dummy `lock`ed operation.  The weaker orders are all free in x86 asm, so fences just need to block compile-time reordering.  [How do memory\_order\_seq\_cst and memory\_order\_acq\_rel differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58043923) / [how are barriers/fences and acquire, release semantics implemented microarchitecturally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58070428)

Comment: I think the details of this callback pointer and its use matter a lot.  The docs are saying the pointed-to function has to be thread-safe which of course makes sense, but is the function pointer also changing *while* OpenCL threads are running?  (Actually a lambda reference or something I guess, which might be worse since it's a code pointer and a captured `this`, so it's wider than 1 pointer width and probably multiple separate stores to update it, so I wouldn't assume it's even atomic in practice unless it's only storing a pointer to that pair of values...)

Comment: In this case the callback is a lambda object, passed by value so no worries there. In general, as always,  one should take care that the objects referenced by the callback, either explicit (e.g. lambda captures by ref or pointers) or implicit (the calling object when using non-static member functions) are valid when the it's being called. Along with other details I've omitted, I actually pass `this` as `std::weak_ptr` generated by `std::enable_shared_from_this` mechanism. So being "atomic" is not a concern w.r.t these operations in the language.